# Showing $2^x$ is a lower bound

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

How do I show that $2^x - x^2 \in \Omega(2^x)$?

Basically, I know that this means that $\exists a, x_0 \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall x \in \mathbb{N}, a.2^x \leq 2^x - x^2$.

I worked around with it a bit and I seemed to have gotten something that makes sense for the case of an upper bound;
$$2^x -x^2 < 2^x + x^2 < 2^{x+1} = 2.2^n $$
Now, if I were trying to find an upper bound, I'd have chosen $a = 2$ and $x_0 = 1$. How do I work the other way around(basically less than or equal to $2^x - x^2$ and prove this lower bound?

Comment: Try $a=\frac 12$...

Comment: @abiessu That clearly does not work.

Comment: since $x=2$ produces $2^x-x^2=0$, there is no value of $a$ that will work.  Or, move the function so it starts at say $x=8$, at which point $a=\frac 12$ will work quite well...

Comment: You can even choose $a=1$ for the upper bound...

Answer (score 1):

For the upper bound, consider $a=1, x_0=1$:

$$\forall x\in \Bbb N, x\ge x_0\\
1\cdot 2^x\ge 2^x-x^2\\
0\ge -x^2$$

For the lower bound, consider $a=\frac 12, x_0=8$:

$$\begin{align}x\in \Bbb N&, y=x+x_0-1\\
\text{to show: }\;a\cdot 2^y&\le 2^y-y^2\\
\frac 12 2^{x+x_0-1}&\le 2^{x+x_0-1}-(x+x_0-1)^2\\
2^{x+6}&\le 2^{x+7}-(x+7)^2\\
2^{x+6}&\ge (x+7)^2\end{align}$$

It should be a simple matter to continue from here, whether directly or with induction.